# How do I bind TwoWay between a CheckBox in a UserControl and the ViewModel in the wider scope?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` that has a `CheckBox` on it. When I consume the `UserControl` on my main XAML page, I'd like to TwoWay bind a property on the control to a property on my ViewModel e.g.

```
<myUserControl BtnIsBlacklisted="{Binding IsBlacklisted, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

When `IsBlacklisted` changes, I'd like my checkbox to change too and vice-versa.

Here is what I have,

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BtnIsBlacklistedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BtnIsBlacklisted", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, new 
            PropertyChangedCallback(BtnIsBlacklistedPropertyChanged))
        );

    private static void BtnIsBlacklistedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... do something here ...
    }

    public bool BtnIsBlacklisted
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(BtnIsBlacklistedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BtnIsBlacklistedProperty, value); }
    }
```

My UserControl has this for the CheckBox,

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" 
    ...
IsChecked="{Binding Path=BtnIsBlacklisted, 
        ElementName=UserControl, 
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToNotBool}, 
        Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The property on my ViewModel object is as follows,

```
    public bool IsBlacklisted
    {
        get 
        {
            return App.VM.BlacklistedRetailers.Contains(this.Retailer);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                App.VM.BlacklistedRetailers.Add(this.Retailer);
            }
            else
            {
                while (App.VM.BlacklistedRetailers.Contains(this.Retailer))
                {
                    App.VM.BlacklistedRetailers.Remove(this.Retailer);
                }
            }
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("IsBlacklisted");
        }
    }
```

The only way `BlacklistedRetailers` changes is through the set method above so there is no need to trigger a `NotifyPropertyChanged` from there ...

I have tried many of the suggestions in other questions i.e.

1. using a dependency property
2. including `Mode=TwoWay`
3. Binding on the `UserControl` using a self-referencing DataContext set on the containing grid (this does not work either).

however none of these have worked.

Some final notes:

- This is for a Windows Phone 7.5 project
- **Edit:** One way binding doe not work either, it seems it there is a problem binding to the `UserControl`'s own properties

Comment: Is your `BoolToNotBool` converter TwoWay aswell?

Comment: It is. I've worked on it a bit more now and I found that it works if I bind directly from the UserControl XAML rather than binding via. the UserControl properties e.g. `IsChecked="{Binding IsBlacklisted,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToNotBool}, Mode=TwoWay}"` however this is not very general since it requires knowing the name of the external ViewModel within the `UserControl` ... I also found out that OneWay binding does not work fine, properties were only being updated because I was setting them in the DependencyPropertyChanged event handler - question updated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ElementName Binding` matches against `x:Name` values which are in the same name scope as the element on which the binding is being set. There's not enough of the code shown to tell but you're using "UserControl" which I'm guessing is not set as the name of the element, but is being used to try and match the type. The `ElementName` also might not be able to resolve if the `CheckBox` is declared inside a template.

Comment: You got it, I set `x:Name="thisUserControl"` in the opening `UserControl` element and referred to it in the Binding as `ElementName=thisUserControl` and it works. Thanks!